# How too look what is in the Isolated Storage (windows phone)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

how can i look, what i saved in the isloated storage untill now?
i try to make a app where user can save more lists. And choose after that which List he wants to have and Display that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very handy tool for viewing the files currently in the isolated storage. Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx).

However, if you're planning on doing this at runtime, then I would suggest checking the following tutorial from MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd5e2z84(v=vs.110).aspx)

This method in particular may be what you are after.

```
public static List<String> GetAllFiles(string pattern, IsolatedStorageFile storeFile)
{
    // Get the root and file portions of the search string. 
    string fileString = Path.GetFileName(pattern);

    List<String> fileList = new List<String>(storeFile.GetFileNames(pattern));

    // Loop through the subdirectories, collect matches, 
    // and make separators consistent. 
    foreach (string directory in GetAllDirectories("*", storeFile))
    {
        foreach (string file in storeFile.GetFileNames(directory + "/" + fileString))
        {
            fileList.Add((directory + "/" + file));
        }
    }

    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much for ur solution!!
I saved my List in IsolatedStorageSetting. Does it have a related code for that?
If not i will Change it in my Code.

Comment: Cause in IsolatedStorageSettings i dont have a Path?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too familiar with IsolatedStorageSettings, but there is a nice tutorial [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/198869-wp7-using-isolatedstoragesettings/), however this is for Windows Phone 7, things may have changed since then. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Application. This is very helpful as it integrates with your device and emulator and you get the Complete Storage Access of How Data is stored in stored in your Emulator or Device and is very flexible as you can Manipulate the storage Contents in Runtime.

[windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/)

Step1: Link you .xap package in debug or release mode

[image]

Step2: Run the Project and you can check the contents here

[image]